# Android change overflow menu text color in AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

Tags: android, colors, styles, themes

I can't find how to change the text color of my overflow menu. I have a toolbar used as ActionBar and the theme is "AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar".

I want overflow menu looking like the popup menu of menu button.

My theme:

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary_RED</item>

        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark_RED</item>

        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colortextColorPrimary</item>

        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colortextColorSecondary</item>

        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionMenuTextColor</item>

    </style>
```

My colors:

```
    <color name="colorPrimary_RED">#d00000</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark_RED">#9d001b</color>
    <color name="colortextColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="colortextColorSecondary">#000000</color>
    <color name="actionMenuTextColor">#000000</color>
```

**Overflow menu text in the screen is pink because I changed it to let people see. It is white.**

Screen of my app:[image]